# Low quality photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, graphic-styles

I have created a photo size of 350*200 pixels. The problem is when I add it to my website it's showing blurry a little bit. Blurry is not good.

How to keep the same size but a higher resolution?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't keep it the same size but have higher resolution. It's not possible.  The number of pixels in a digital image **is** the resolution.  As to the blurriness, that may be because your computer has system scaling enabled - so the browser is scaling the image, which will make it look blurry.